# Specified cast is not valid when filtering a DataTable where the column can be int32 or int64

Tags: c#, linq, casting, datatable

So im filtering a DataTable based on a supplied column name and filter. 
I've specified the filter as Int64 so that it can support both Int32 and Int64 filter values.

Below is the code im using to perform the filtering.

```
private DataTable FilterDataTableByInt(DataTable dt, string columnName, Int64 filter)
{
    DataTable Newdt = new DataTable();

    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var result = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where myRow.Field<Int64>(columnName) == filter
                      select myRow);

        Newdt = result.AsDataView().ToTable();
    }

    return Newdt;
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine when the column im filtering by is an Int64 value. However I get the cast exception if the column is an Int32. It exceptions in the area `myRow.Field<Int64>(columnName)`

Any idea how I can rewrite this to support both Int32 and Int64 column types in the DataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Convert.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
where Convert.ToInt64(myRow[columnName]) == filter
select myRow
```

Comment: Cool. Works perfectly.